# Cast object to IEnumerable<object>?

Tags: c#, casting

How can I cast an `object` to `IEnumerable<object>`?

I know that the object implements `IEnumerable<object>` but I don't know what type it is. It could be an array, a `List<T>`, or whatever.

---

A simple test case I'm trying to get working:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    foreach (var item in arr as IEnumerable<object>)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Can you give us an example?

Comment: @Ani: I have a Dictionary<string,object> containing a bunch of objects of mixed types. Some of them are enumerable. I'm trying to figure out how I can loop over those ones without knowing their exact type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's hard to answer this without a concrete use-case, but you *may*  find it sufficient  to simply cast to the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface.

There are two reasons why this will normally work for most types that are considered "sequences".

1. The "classic" .NET 1.x collection classes implement `IEnumerable`.
2. The generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface inherits from `IEnumerable`,  so the cast should work fine for the generic collection classes in System.Collections.Generic, LINQ sequences etc.

**EDIT**:

As for why your provided sample doesn't work:

1. This wouldn't work in C# 3 because it doesn't support generic interface covariance - you can't view an `IEnumerable<Derived>` as an `IEnumerable<Base>`.
2. This wouldn't work in C# 4 either despite the fact that `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, since variance is not supported for value-types - the cast from `int[]` (an `IEnumerable<int>`) ***-->*** `IEnumerable<object>`  can't succeed.

Comment: Oh... thought it had to be `IEnumerable<T>`. If this works, why wouldn't `IEnumerable<object>` work?... wait... nevermind. Because it's `IEnumerable<int>` which is quite different. I see now. Thanks Ani !

Comment: IEnumerable<T> implements IEnumerable so you can always cast "downwards"

Comment: @Pauli: yes, but the problem I was experiencing was that `int[]` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<object>` at all... only `IEnumerable<int>` which is not the same. But simply `IEnumerable` does do the trick.

Comment: correct, and which you may have realized by now IEnumerable<object> is not the same as IEnumerable even though both their Enumerators return object :)

Comment: I didn't even know they added that in C#4! That's cool. I've probably used it a few times without knowing it :p That stuff still kinda confuses me (covariance/contravariance).

Answer (score 20):

I ran into the same issue with covariance not supporting value types, I had an `object` with and actual type of `List<Guid>` and needed an `IEnumerable<object>`. A way to generate an IEnumerable when just IEnumerable isn't good enough is to use the linq Cast method

```
((IEnumerable)lhsValue).Cast<object>()
```