# cast an object to an Object() with nullable dates

Tags: vb.net, casting

I am currently fighting an old api and I am facing the following problem: I get runtime exceptions when I try to cast an Object to an array of Objects when the values are nullable dates.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(Misc.dateCast(New Nullable(Of DateTime)()))
        Console.WriteLine(Misc.tabledateCast(New Nullable(Of DateTime)() {New DateTime()}))
    End Sub
End Module

Module Misc
    Function dateCast(ByVal val As Nullable(Of DateTime)) As Object
        Return CType(val, Object)
    End Function

    Function tabledateCast(ByVal val As Object) As Object()
        Return CType(val, IEnumerable(Of Object)).Cast(Of Object).ToArray
    End Function
End Module
```

The first cast is working, but not the second. How to cast successfully to an array of objects?

I cannot use `CType(val, IEnumerable(Of Nullable(Of DateTime)))` because the function may get arrays of other types.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632313/cast-object-to-ienumerableobject) answer. Apparently you can cast to `IEnumerable` but not to the generic version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got two choices:

1) If the arrays themselves are type-safe, you can genericize the method so that it knows what to cast to before casting to an object - not the nicest code to look at, especially in VB.NET:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(Misc.tabledateCast(Of Nullable(Of DateTime))(New Nullable(Of DateTime)() {New DateTime()}))
    End Sub
End Module

Module Misc
    Function tabledateCast(Of T)(ByVal val As Object) As Object()
        Return CType(val, IEnumerable(Of T)).Cast(Of Object).ToArray
    End Function
End Module
```

2) Laoujin's link, where you do a non-generic `IEnumerable` cast first:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(Misc.tabledateCast(New Nullable(Of DateTime)() {New DateTime()}))
    End Sub
End Module

Module Misc
    Function tabledateCast(ByVal val As Object) As Object()
        Return CType(val, IEnumerable).Cast(Of Object).ToArray
    End Function
End Module
```